# Flutter OnboardingScreen

Tags: flutter

i'm new to flutter and i'm making a movie app right now for my university project. So i make the full app (not finished yet) and i want to add the OnboardingScreen so when the user open the app it gonna goes to the OnboardingScreen and then to the homepage. i have several question
-where do i put the Onboarding class? (like implementing the Onboarding class)
-how to make it only once, like when the user already open the app, it goes directly to homepage?

here are the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreen createState() => _OnboardingScreen();
}

class _OnboardingScreen extends State<Onboarding> {
  final int _numPages = 3;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int _currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _numPages; i++) {
      list.add(i == _currentPage ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
    }
    return list;
  }

  Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 8.0,
      width: isActive ? 24.0 : 16.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isActive ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF7B51D3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Color(0xff112339),
                Color(0xff112339),
                Colors.black,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => print('Skip'),
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome',
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome',
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 300.0,
                                width: 300.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome',
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                            Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _pageController.nextPage(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print('Get started'),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Movie App',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  // fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                button: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 30),
          )),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear to me.do you want to add a splash screen? like facebook app, when user open the app, the facebook logo with custom background float for quite sec,then the homepage.
or you want a specific page that show some content for specific second (like 2-3 sec ) then to the home page?

Comment: no, i mean like i haven't called the Onboard class, and i don't know where to call it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, you need to change your logic a bit, at first, call the `Onboarding` screen, user will see that, if they want to skip or get started, then sent them to `HomePage`.

If this ius suitable for you, then change in main.dart file  `home: HomePage()` to `home: Onboarding()`.Here You are calling your OnBoarding screen/class. user will see the content of it, If they want to start the app or skip the `onboarding` screen, then sent them to the homepage of the app.
To do that, change your code in Onboarding class `onPressed: () => print('Skip')` to this

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
              },
```

And `onTap: () => print('Get started'),` to this

```
onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
              },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that user sees something - an onboarding screen in your case, for the first time when the app is started on the device by using [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store a trigger flag. I do this like so:

```
Future<bool> checkIfFirstTimeUser() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool firstTimeHere = prefs.getBool('showHelloRoutine') ?? true;
  await prefs.setBool('showHelloRoutine', false);
  return firstTimeHere;
}
```

Call this function somewhere on app loading and save the returned value in a bool. Then in the widgets part you can do:

```
showOnboarding ? OnboardingScreen() : MainAppScreen()
```

Comment: I would also suggest this approach.